# Facebook. How to ban user from my Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to ask you here is way to ban user not from Facebook page, but from app? I mean I need to ban cheaters from my game, If I give them ban from page, they still can play.

So I saw that in Facebook is command like `banned` and as I understand I need to make array with usernames / user id which I want to ban. But I don't know how to use It correctly. Please help me with It.

Here is my part of code:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
$coded = $_REQUEST['code'];


//echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];
$name = $user_profile['name'];
//$id = $user_profile['id'];
session_start();
$_SESSION['vardas'] = $name;

$times = $_SESSION['test'];
$username = $_SESSION['test1'];


//echo $facebook->getAccessToken();


    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      $user = null;
      error_log($e);
    }
  } else {
$redirectUri = 'http://www.facebook.com/EUROKOS/app_170337839812071?ref=ts';
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
        'scope' => 'publish_stream,photo_upload',
        'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri
    ));
    echo("<script>top.location.href = '" . $loginUrl . "';</script>");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ban a user using the API and your app access_token. It's pretty easy to ban / unban a user. [This tutorial details out how to go about it](https://www.webniraj.com/2013/08/15/facebook-api-banning-users-from-your-application/).